# How to print out sum of row and column in R?

Tags: r

How to print out some of row and some of column in R?

```r
mat <- matrix(c(2,5,7,2,5,3,6,8,1,1,1,1,2,2,3),nrow=3,ncol=5)
mat
```

Here is my original matrix.

```
2   2   6   1   2

5   5   8   1   2

7   3   1   1   3
```

I have to make a matrix like this.

```
2   2   6   1   2   13

5   5   8   1   2   21

7   3   1   1   3   15

14  10  15  3   7   49
```

new row is the sum of original matrix row elements, new column is the sum of original column matrix elements.
49 is the sum of original matrix elements.

I'm trying to use apply, but apply just print out sum of elements individually.

How can I do that?

how to solve this problem?
what method do I have to use?

Comment: There is a `base R` function for this `addmargins(mat)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addMargins(mat)` as suggested by akrun, or, if you want a standard matrix result, you can do:

```r
mat2 <- cbind(mat, rowSums(mat))

rbind(mat2, colSums(mat2))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    2    2    6    1    2   13
#> [2,]    5    5    8    1    2   21
#> [3,]    7    3    1    1    3   15
#> [4,]   14   10   15    3    7   49
```